# SQL Server mirroring_partner_instance does not have FQDN

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, database-mirroring

There are two SQL Server instances with mirroring setup. ServerA is primary and ServerB is mirror. Below is my connection string

```
jdbc:sqlserver://ServerA.company.com\\AB002;portNumber=23112;databaseName=SomeDBName;integratedSecurity=false;failoverPartner=ServerB.company.com\\CD002
```

When ServerA is up and running as primary, application connects to the database successfully and everything works as expected. When ServerA failsover to ServerB, application is unable to connect to ServerB. Below is the error message from application logs

> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not
>   get JDBC Connection; nested exception is
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
>   to the host ServerB, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the
>   connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is
>   running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make
>   sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

It should be connecting to ServerB.company.com based on the connection string. After some research, found that the driver ignores the failover information in the connection string and caches it from the primary database on initial connection to the primary from `database_mirroring` table. Here is how my `database_mirroring` table looks like

```
DatabaseName | mirroring_role_desc | mirroring_safety_level_desc | mirroring_state_desc | mirroring_partner_instance
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SomeDBName   | PRINCIPAL           | OFF                         | SYNCHRONIZED         | ServerB\CD002
```

If you look at the column `mirroring_partner_instance`, it does not have the FQDN for the mirroring instance and the application is unable to resolve the name. I was able to fix this locally by adding an entry in the hosts file for `ServerB`

Adding hosts entry on all production servers is not going to be possible. Has anyone faced this issue before? Is there any other way to solve this issue other than adding hosts entry?

Comment: Maybe it is silly question, but Is your  ServerB really running on port 1433? Did you tried to specify portNumber for  ServerB?

Comment: Its not running on port 1433. It is able to failover to ServerB on right port (23112) when I added the hosts entry to resolve ServerB

Comment: So you resolved this by yourself already?

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned in my question that I am able to solve this by adding hosts file entry. But It is not feasible to make that hosts file entry on all production servers. I am looking for alternative solutions